# table row as a counter in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I would like to know how could I assign a table row an id which is systematically as a counter. It can be a string + a counter as follow:

```
<table>
   <tr id="Row1"> # it can be only a number => id="1"
   <tr id="Row2"> # it can be only a number => id="2"
   <tr id="Row3"> # it can be only a number => id="3"
   .....
   <tr id="Row5000"> # it can be only a number => id="5000"
</table
```

Because I have thousands of rows and then could not assign id to them manually. This is why I want to assign them via XSLT. Does anybody know how could I do so? Thanks.

Comment: you want to assign an id using javaScript?

Comment: @nomantufail sure it can be both CSS or JS.

Comment: This could be straight-forward in XSLT too, using `position()` but you would have to post a sample of your XML and your current XSLT for a precise answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// javascript

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
{
for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
table[i].setAttribute("id",i+1);
}
```

//jquery

```
$("table tr").each(function(index,object) {
object.attr("id",(index+1));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr").each(function(i, tr) {tr.id = 'Row' + (i+1);})
```

explanation: you can find each tr in table and assign id for each one.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But in general when there would be many tables with proper id's then this will make a problem. Because there would be two id's which is pity, right?

Comment: @Royeh, yes, but you can use unique prefix (like 'Row') for different tables. Or do not use id and use classes.

Answer (score 1):

First you assign an id attribute to your table like this

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  ....
</table>
```

Then add a script at the bottom of your document

```
<script>
 (function() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
    for(var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i-1].id = 'Row'+i;
    }  
 })();
```

Its a pure javascript solution. No jQuery required.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your table an id. here its newTable then iterate and set the attibute

```
<script>
    function getit(){
    $('#newTable').find('tr').each(function(index){
          var x= this.setAttribute("id","Row"+[index]);
        console.log(x);
        })
    }
    </script>
```

hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

### You Can Use This:
Your CSS

```
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

table tbody tr th::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section);
}

table tbody tr th::before {
    content: counter(section);
}
</style>
```

### Your Html

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">f1</th>
                    <th scope="col">f2</th>
                    <th scope="col">f3</th>
                    <th scope="col">f4</th>
                    <th scope="col">f5</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-middle" scope="row"></th>
                    <td class="align-middle">d1</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">d2</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">d3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-middle" scope="row"></th>
                    <td class="align-middle">d1</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">d2</td>
                    <td class="align-middle">d3</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```