# assigning index number to row in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add an index number to each row in a table automatically, like the one in the screenshot that I got from bootstrap's site [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elwWw.png), I have tried multiple solutions but kept getting an index of -1 for all the rows, I would really appreciate the help, thank.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: run after page load: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064085/table-row-as-a-counter-in-html

Comment: Show one of the solutions you tried and we'll help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
// tbl is the table
var rows = tbl.rows; n = 1;
for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  row = rows[i];
  f = row.firstElementChild;
  if (f) {
    el = document.createElement(f.tagName);
    el.innerHTML = (f.tagName == "TH") ? "#" : n;
    row.insertBefore(el, f);
    if (f.tagName != "TH") n++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly, i have also tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064085/table-row-as-a-counter-in-html
which is mentioned by @Yarin_007 and also worked, thanks

Comment: Why can't table be the table and element be the element?